# Firebase Requested entity was not found when new APNs Authentification Key was generated

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, cloud

My question is the following:
I created a new APNs Authentification Key because I lost my previous one. I saw this message inside the Cloud Messaging tab in the Firebase console:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging can use either an APNs authentication key or APNs certificate to connect with APNs.

By creating a new APNS Authentification Key now I don't get the previous error before adding the APNS Authentification Key to Firebase

> Error: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service Raw server response: "{"error":{"code":401,"message":"Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service","status":"UNAUTHENTICATED","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError","errorCode":"THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_ERROR"}]}}"

Now I get the following error: `Requested entity was not found`

How can I fix this error, and why is it happening?